# NGINX + Docker Compose Routing Issues

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, uri, microservices

I have a docker compose file comprising of two microservices that I want to leverage URI routing for in order to handle CORS. Here is my compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  auth-api:
    image: xxxx/auth-api:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - "user-api"
  user-api:
    image: xxxx/user-api:latest
    restart: always
nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    links:
      - "auth-api"
      - "user-api"
    volumes:
       - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
```

I want to use NGINX for the routing but am running into issues with 404's or 405's when trying to access the resources. I've tried several different configurations and for a while NGINX was saying it couldn't find the api endpoints when it started which I resolved so I think my issue is mostly around routing configuration. I want it to be `/auth` and `/user` for those requests.

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream auth-target {
      server auth-api:8080;
    }

    upstream user-target {
        server user-api:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;

        location /auth {

            proxy_pass http://auth-target;

            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location /user {

            proxy_pass  http://user-target;

            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }


    }

}
```

I'm pretty new to NGINX so I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right. I should also note that both APIs have 8080 exposed as part of the container build.

Answer (score 1):

So here was my issue. The routing was working but I was returning 404's from my services. This was because the Location route was being passed along with the request. So in the end I found this answer:

https://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass

Where it points that you need a trailing slash in order to remove the location so my config file ended up looking something like this:

```
location /auth/ {

            proxy_pass http://auth-target/;

            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
```